# Make subdirs of git repository their own git repos

Tags: git

> As it turns out, this question asked the same thing [Detach (move) subdirectory into separate Git repository](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/359424/detach-subdirectory-into-separate-git-repository)

I decided to learn git and to keep my programming homework in a git repo.  I think it was a good idea.  Now I'm wondering about something:

I had a single git repo with a subdirectory for each assignment.  I'm wondering if there's a sane way to make each of the subdirectories into its own git repo, retaining the history associated with those files.  It seems like "git filter-branch --subirectory-filter" is part of the answer, but I'm not sure what to do.

EDIT

To clarify:  My structure is like this

```
superdir  
  .git  
  subdir1
  subdir2
  subdir3
```

I'd like my structure to be more like this

```
superdir    
  subdir1
    .git
  subdir2
    .git
  subdir3
    .git
```

Can I do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're probably looking for [git submodules](http://book.git-scm.com/5_submodules.html), but I'd just change your layout to have the top level *not* be a git repo and just have the subdir repos managed independently.

Comment: So I thought about that, but from what I understand, that would require the subdirectories to already be their own git repositories; am I wrong?

Comment: Yes, either of my suggestions will require the subdirs to be git repos. Getting into `filter-branch` stuff is just a recipe for pain.

Comment: You could do a one-time run through of all your stuff and make them repos using something like the process described in the accepted answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/359424/detach-subdirectory-into-separate-git-repository

Comment: I should have found that question.  It's exactly what I was wondering.

Answer (score 2):

Use a script such as the one below:

```
#! /bin/bash

superdir=file:///tmp/superdir
subdirs=(subdir1 subdir2 subdir3)

for dir in ${subdirs[@]}; do
  echo "Rewriting $dir..."
  git clone --quiet $superdir "$dir" || exit 1
  cd "$dir"

  # workaround for git-1.6.4.2 on Cygwin 1.7
  # otherwise, git-filter-branch complains about a dirty branch
  git reset --hard -q

  git filter-branch --subdirectory-filter "$dir" HEAD >/dev/null
  git reflog expire --expire=0 --all
  git gc --quiet --prune=0
  cd ..
done
```

Starting with a superdir repo whose structure is

```
$ ls -a . *
.:
.  ..  .git  subdir1  subdir2  subdir3

subdir1:
.  ..  file1

subdir2:
.  ..  file2

subdir3:
.  ..  file3
```

the result is

```
$ ls -a . *
.:
.  ..  subdir1 subdir2  subdir3

subdir1:
.  ..  .git  file1

subdir2:
.  ..  .git  file2

subdir3:
.  ..  .git  file3
```

Answer (score 1):

Why not place each class as it's own repo and each assignment as it's own branch?  As I look back on my college coursework, that is how I would organize things.

Comment: That might make more sense.  Again, my initial configuration was not very good.  I'm wondering if I can reconfigure it in a better way.